# ScrollView will not scroll to the bottom of the contact List

Tags: react-native

Im creating a contact list.
To do that I have put the contact data into a scroll view.
When the user typed a letter to the search contact and tried to go to the last contact in the list, it won't be shown( it will show a little and it will bounce back up.)

```
        return (
            <SafeAreaView>
              <ScrollView style={{flexGrow: 1}} bounces={false} >
                <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', borderTopWidth: 0.5, borderTopColor: 'grey'}}>
                  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <Text onPress={() => setChecked(true)} style={{ fontSize: 20, marginHorizontal: 10 }}>
                      {item.name + ' '}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 17, marginHorizontal: 10, marginTop: 5, color: 'grey' }}>
                      {item.phoneNumbers && item.phoneNumbers[0] && phone && item.phoneNumbers[0].digits}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {
                      onChangeValue(item);
                    }}
                  >
                    <CheckBox
                      style={{ width: 15, height: 15, paddingTop: 8 }}
                      right={true}
                      checked={!!selectedContacts[phoneNumber]}
                      onPress={() => {
                        onChangeValue({ item });
                      }}
                    />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
```

I did some research and they said to use flexGrow 1 on the scrollView or to make a parent view with flex 1 but none of that was a solution.

How can I show the user the bottom contacts when the user scrolls to the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

please use `flex:1` in the `scrollView` like this.

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'column', flex: 1, width: wp(100)}}>
          <WaterfallList
            data={FinalArray}
            bounces={false}
            onMomentumScrollBegin={onScrollStart}
            onMomentumScrollEnd={onScrollEnd}
            heightForItem={item => Dimensions.get('screen').width * 0.6}
            numColumns={2}
            allLoaded={true}
            onLoading={() => console.log('dsd')}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            contentStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              paddingHorizontal: Dimensions.get('screen').width * 0.03,

              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            }}
            renderItem={ContactItemServer}
          />
    </View>
```